# HTTP Call to Docker Container redirects IP to Docker ID

Tags: python, hadoop, docker, ip, hdfs

I am running a Hadoop Docker container on a Windows 10 machine. I am trying to write a Python program using [this](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) library to access my HDFS. I am able to list folder contents with my client configured with "http://localhost:50070" (50070 is the webHDFS port). However, when I try to read the content of a file, I get an error saying that the address could not be resolved. In the error returned, the host is the ID of my Docker container "453af3bd9164" instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as I would expect.

I have tried using different Docker containers and different Python libraries and still get similar errors. So my guess is that I am not configuring my Docker or Hadoop environments correctly. Since I can access the NameNode WebUI from my Docker host machine and listing folder contents works properly, I think my datanode configurations could be the problem. When I check through the WebUI, my datanode shows as "In Service" so it is at least running.

How can I configure my environment correctly so that HTTP calls to my HDFS datanode work properly?

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50075</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2 453af3bd9164
192.168.56.1 192.168.56.1
```

Comment: I no zero about hadoop, but....   I'm pretty sure you never want to use localhost in the configuration.   Use real host names.

Answer (score 2):

After hours and hours of digging around, I finally fixed the issue. Maybe this is obvious to some people, but hopefully I can help noobs like me by posting my solution.

When I first ran my docker, I didn't specify a hostname to use for my container, so it was assigned a random default value which in this case was 453af3bd9164. However, this causes DNS lookup issues and you need to make sure your Docker container's host computer name and the docker container's name are the same. So I added this flag:

```
docker run -h "computer-name@example.com"
```

I also added this property to my hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
    <value>false</false>
</property>
```

Doing these 2 things allowed me to read/write to my datanodes.